# How to limit memory usage with PDO in MariaDB : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb, sql-injection

I am changing my SQL request to PDO in order to integrate more security against SQL injecting.  I was using before procedural msqli and everything was working ok.  Now I updated server to PHP 8.2 and I am using PDO and prepared statements.

The BD I am accessing is old MariaDB and has a table with 247 fields most of which are `NULL` on a single row. (It is sections for a description of mushrooms, but only some of each are really described in a single row (mushrooms)).

Most of the 247 fields are set to `mediumtext` because they can content up to a couple paragraphs.

My connection script is :

```
try {

    db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$servername;charset=utf8mb4", $username, $password );

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Erreur de connection: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
return;
}
```

When I select one row of that table in order to echo the not NULL descriptions column, as soon as I execute the statement I run into a full memory.  The error is at the `stmt->execute()` line, not even at the fetchAll line.

```
$description = 'someTag';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM description WHERE tag = :tag LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':tag', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

The error :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/mycoqueb/public_html/nou.mycoquebec.org/scripts/bd-query.php on line (**the $stmt->execute() line)
```

I tried to use :

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

Instead of fetchAll() but it changed noting, I used it on every other request from the same page and it changed noting.  I flushed variables that were no more useful to `NULL` on the rest of the page and it changed nothing.  I even isolated the script on an empty page and it exceeds the memory limit.

I tried to add this to my connection script and it changed nothing :

```
db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

I tried to select only one field instead of `*` and this worked, but I don't have an easy way to find `NOT NULL` columns in the table for a specific tag (row).

I tried to find a SQL statement to restrict my `SELECT` to `NOT NULL` columns but I was not successful.

I know I could get add `memory_limit = 256M` to the phpini file, but that is not what I want since the website has a high usage and for now its on a multihosted server.

The best solution would be to reengineer the MariaDB database using a table with description sections labels and linking only used sections to the main `description` table for each row, but I have limited access to the db since it is online with the old website and the old website needs to stay online and up to date for 1-2 years after new deployment. I though of creating a daily cron job to do that but I would like to avoid for the moment.

Any Idea how I can get this to work?  It was working fine using msqli on php 8.1.

To answer the worries of contributors that think it's related to another part of the page code, here is the complete code of the isolated test page.

```
function convert($size)
 {
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
 }


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPass";
$dbname = "myDB";


try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$servername;charset=utf8mb4", $username, $password );

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

 } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Erreur de connection: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    return;
}   

$query = (array_key_exists("query",$_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["query"] : "");


if($query != ""){

    $tag_desc = 'Aegerita candida';
    // Code works if I limit to "SELECT Titre FROM description WHERE tag = :tag LIMIT 1";
    $sql_description = "SELECT * FROM description WHERE tag = :tag LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_description);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tag', $tag_desc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    echo convert(memory_get_usage(true));  // returns 2mb
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $i = 0;
    
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        if($i == 0) {

            ?><table style="border-collapse:collapse;border: 0;table-layout: fixed;color: #063850;background-color: #DDDDDD;text-align: left"><thead><tr style="border: 2px solid #063850;"> <?php
            foreach (array_keys($row) as $key) {
                //print_r($key);
                echo ("<th style='padding:5px;border: 2px solid #063850;position:sticky;top: -2;z-index:10;background-color:#e5a045'>$key</th>");
            }
            echo ("</tr></thead>");
        }

        $i++;

        echo ("<tr style='border: 2px solid #063850'>");
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo ("<td style='padding:2px;border: 2px solid #063850'>$value</td>");
            // <img src=\"$value\" height=\"400\" >
        }
        echo ("</tr>");
    }
    
    if ($i > 0) {
        echo ("</table>");
        echo ('<div style="margin-top:400px">&nbsp;</div>');
    } else {
        echo "Aucun résultat";
    }

}

$db = null;
```

Has mentioned it automatically work if I limit my sql to a couple fields.

The error is still on the `stmt->execute()` line.

Comment: There's probably a lot more in the page that this `$stmt->execute()` line is part of, and it's probably that other code that uses a lot of memory. In isolation this code wouldn't use that much memory.

Comment: This does not seem to be a mysql issue, but a php / pdo one. In sql you have to tell in advance which columns you want to include in the resultset, you can't do this dynamically. I agree with @KIKOSoftware, you need to take a look at all code in that page and figure out wjat uses lots of memory!

Comment: You could place [echo memory_get_usage();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) at strategic places in your code to see where the memory is being used.

Comment: Try fetching the results row by row instead of fetching all rows at once. while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

Comment: @KIKOSoftware as I said I isolated the script on a complete virgin page and the problem persists.  It is automatically ok if I change * for one of the column name.  I added the complete isolated page code to the question.

Comment: @AlexVio First rule of any data retrieval is NEVER use SELECT * - for this very reason to avoid lifelong troubles.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: But then you **need** to know which columns you need/want to have, and that seems to be the only problem in this question... 

Comment: @Luuk I agree thats my problem !

Comment: Use SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and SELECT only the columns you need.  An alternative, if you have RAM available is use of MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET of 1G (the limit) to see if you can get through it.  This is a PER CONNECT expansion.  If you have a 4G server and 32 concurrent users you will be OutOfMemory before you can take your next breath.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware juste before the `stmt->execute()` line the `echo convert(memory_get_usage(true))` answer is 2mb.  After that line the program bugs as you know...

Comment: @WilsonHauck my specific problem is I have no way to find the columns I need apart from knowing that its not `NULL`.  Different mushroom species have different description sections used..  I know the problem comes from really bad database structure, but for now I am stuck with it.

Comment: @PatrickSimard Has mentionned already it changes nothing for my specific problem but I changed it in all my other pages I edited my sample page code but it stills run out of memory at `$stmt->execute()` line

Comment: You could (try to) normalize your date, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/7ZHLjCmI

Comment: I tried to create a test table with 247 columns of mediumtext, but I get an error that the row size is too great. I tried with fewer columns, and got it to work after I reduced it to 196 columns. So I question how is your table really designed?

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for the sql test page.  My issue is that most of the rows have 5 to 20 not NULL columns and not any columns is NULL in all rows.  So I end out not normalizing anything.  I am looking at redesigning this crazy table!

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't know how the guy made it.  When I export it to a fiddle MySQL it is too large...

Comment: If you use `SHOW CREATE TABLE description` what is the storage engine? There should be a clause at the end like `ENGINE=InnoDB` but it may be a different engine.

Comment: @BillKarwin It is InnoDB.  I cant add the whole result in this answer too long.  Here is the last line `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5880 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_swedish_ci`

Comment: Can you run `SELECT @@version;` and report the result?

Comment: @BillKarwin `10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve-log`

Comment: Okay, I've edited to make it more clear that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. Please be aware that these are not the same database product. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed a lot since then, and not always in compatible ways. Answers for one are not necessarily applicable to the other, so you should be clear when asking questions on Stack Overflow which one you're using.

Comment: Increase `max_allowed_packet` and/or check sizes of strings being inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that the issue is your data model?

If you have a table that has a lot of `null`s, then the data is most likely not normalized.

Instead of having 256 columns in your table, maybe just have the ones that are always there, and then relate it to a separate table with three fields: foreign key to the main table, a tag field and a value field.

If you are rewriting your application to USE PDO anyway, some long-term considerations could be included.

## Example table

### Layout like yours (all data in one table):

| id | name | email | someotherdata | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 | tag4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jaques | j@lullaby.fr | blablabla | NULL | a | NULL | 100 |
| 2 | Allouette | a@lullaby.fr | blébléblé | c | a | NULL | 400 |
| 3 | Mogens | m@lullaby.dk | blæblæblæ | NULL | NULL | 5000 | NULL |
| 4 | Birthe | b@lullaby.dk | bløbløblø | NULL | a | NULL | 100 |

### Suggested Tag-Value table layout

Main Table

| id | name | email | someotherdata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jaques | j@lullaby.fr | blablabla |
| 2 | Allouette | a@lullaby.fr | blébléblé |
| 3 | Mogens | m@lullaby.dk | blæblæblæ |
| 4 | Birthe | b@lullaby.dk | bløbløblø |

Tag-Value Table

| id | tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tag2 | a |
| 1 | tag4 | 100 |
| 2 | tag1 | c |
| 2 | tag2 | a |
| 2 | tag4 | 400 |
| 3 | tag3 | 5000 |
| 4 | tag2 | a |
| 4 | tag4 | 100 |

## Usage

Instead of selecting just your row, you WILL need to either join the results together, or make two separate calls. I would suggest two calls, especially since you are rtunning into memory issues.

```sql
SELECT 
  id, 
  name,
  email,
  someotherdata
FROM
  MainTable
WHERE
  id = 1;

-- and then the tags
SELECT 
  id, 
  tag,
  value
FROM
  TagValueTable
WHERE
  id = 1; -- reference to the main table
```

## Advantaages of this normalized approach

- Less bloat (not so many nulls)
- Simpler structures
- REST ready
- More resilient

  - Add tags without changing the DDL of the database (ALTER)
- You can still get the original layout by making subselects and transpositions in mysql
- You can easily make statistics on the tags related to each other

## Disadvantages

- Complexity of the data model increases
- You need to do a lot of extra SQL gymnastics to get EXACTLY what you had before

Comment: I know this is the way to go.  Thanks for your help.  I am looking forward to redo the data models.  I was hoping a temp solution for the migration, but I think I will probably take time to redo the db while in transition.  Hopefuly most of the other tables are in a good structure.  Its the description one that get me in trouble...

Comment: @AlexVio In my opinion this is all about learning and improving. if you edit your question and post the DDL (create statements)  we might be able to suggest an interim stage. Depending on what your solution is used for it may be advantageous to prepare everything and do a mass migration, instead of going via an interim solution. We can only help  based on what we are provided with. The alternate is using codereview.SE or the DBA.SE

Comment: I finally devleopped a simple script and created tables as suggested.  It works well with some adaption to my queries for showing the data.  I used Join statments. I will create a crohn jod to update the new tables every day until we stop using the old site.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

I finally followed @JoSSte concept and created two tables and used JOIN SQL request to reproduce the result.  I know this is the best way to go for the long run.

I am still wondering though why am I easily capable of creating the original fetch with MySQLI : `$rows = $db->execute_query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` without creating stress on the memory and I instantly run out of memory with PDO...

For interest this is the SQL and crohn job for creating and populating the two tables the two new tables from the original.

SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE `RubriquesTitres` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Titre` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Ordre` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Nom` (`Titre`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `Ordre` (`Ordre`) USING BTREE
) 

CREATE TABLE `RubriqueItems` (
  `ID` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Especes_ID` int(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Synchronisé en CronJob avec MyCardex',
  `tag` varchar(60) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Clé externe (MyCardex)',
  `DerniereCorrection` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `RubriqueID` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `RubriqueTitre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `RubriqueTexte` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Especes_ID` (`Especes_ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tag` (`tag`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `LienTag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag`) REFERENCES `MyCARDEX` (`tag`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

CRON JOB

```
$sql_description = "SELECT * FROM description LIMIT 1501,6000";

$rows = $db->execute_query($sql_description)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($row as $label => $value) {
            // This part of code was run once for creating the original main table with Tag titles
            /*
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `RubriquesTitres` (`Titre`,`Ordre`) VALUES ('$label', " . ($i * 10) . ")";
            $db->execute_query($sql);
            */
        
        // Excluding some main table columns that are not in the tag table
        if ($value != "" && $value != NULL && $label != "ID_D" && $label != "Especes_ID" && $label !== "tag" && $label != "groupe" && $label != "groupeN" && $label != "nomlat" && $label != "nomcourant" && $label != "DerniereCorrection") { 
            $i++;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `RubriqueItems` (`Especes_ID`,`tag`,`DerniereCorrection`,`RubriqueID`,`RubriqueTitre`,`RubriqueTexte`) VALUES ('" . $row['Especes_ID'] . "', '" . $row['tag'] . "', '" . $row['DerniereCorrection'] . "', '" . getRubriqueID($label) . "', '$label', '" . addslashes($value) . "')";
            
            $ok = $db->execute_query($sql);
            
            echo $row['tag'] . '<br>';
            
        }

    }
}
```

AND here is some of my retrieve code :

```
$sql = "SELECT RubriqueItems.RubriqueTitre AS Titre, RubriqueItems.RubriqueTexte AS Texte
        FROM RubriqueItems
        INNER JOIN RubriquesTitres ON RubriqueItems.RubriqueID = RubriquesTitres.ID
        INNER JOIN MyCARDEX ON RubriqueItems.tag = MyCARDEX.tag
        WHERE RubriqueItems.tag = :tag
        ORDER BY RubriquesTitres.Ordre ASC";

$stmt = $dbPDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':tag', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
$i = 0;   
while($rubrique = $stmt->fetch()) {

    if ($rubrique['Titre'] != "" && $rubrique['Texte'] != "" && $rubrique['Titre'] != "Titre") { 
        $output .= '<p class="texte-titre2">' . $rubrique['Titre'] . '</p><p id="' . $rubrique['Titre'] . '" class="texte-titre3">' .  ($rubrique['Titre'] == "Références" || $rubrique['Titre'] == "Confirmation moléculaire" ? linkUrlsInTrustedHtml(nl2br(ucfirst($rubrique['Texte'])))  :  ($showGlossaire ? ajouter_glossaire(nl2br(ucfirst($rubrique['Texte'])),$glossaire) : nl2br(ucfirst($rubrique['Texte'])))) . '</p>'; 
        $i++;
    }

}

$stmt->closeCursor();
```